# Git - Syncing a Github repo with a local one?

Tags: linux, git, github

First off, forgive me if this is a duplicate question. I don't know anything but the basic terminology, and it's difficult to find an answer just using laymen's terms.

I made a project, and I made a repository on Github. I've been able to work with that and upload stuff to it for some time, on Windows. The Github Windows application is nice, but I wish there was a GUI for the Linux git.

I want to be able to download the source for this project, and be able to edit it on my Linux machine, and be able to do `git commit -m 'durrhurr'` and have it upload it to the master repository.

Comment: Leaning the basic git commands will be very helpful for you. If you want a GUI and work with Linux you could try Rabbit here http://rabbitvcs.org/

Comment: Git has two in its source tree: `gitk` (history visualization) and `git gui` (generally GUI to its commands)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Forgive me if you've already done most of this:

The first step is to set up your ssh keys if you are trying to go through ssh, if you are going through https you can skip this step. Detailed instructions are provided at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

The next step is to make a local clone of the repository. Using the command line it will be `git clone <url>` The url you should be able to find on your github page.

After that you should be able to commit and push over the command line using `git commit -am "commit message"` and `git push`

Comment: I actually had no idea what the SSH keys were for. 
So I did all of that, and it worked. Thanks!
I'm still considering installing a GUI for it, but at least I have the terminal to fall back on.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `SmartGit` for a GUI for git on Linux: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html

But learning git first on the command line is generally a good idea:

Below are some basic examples assuming you are only working from the `master` branch:

Example for starting a local repo based on what you have from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/sampson-chen/sack.git
```

To see the status of the repo, do:

```
git status
```

Example for syncing your local repo to more recent changes on github:

```
git pull
```

Example for adding new or modified files to a "stage" for commit

```
git add /path/file1 /path/file2
```

Think of the stage as the files that you explicitly tell git to keep track of for revision control. git will see the all the files in the repo (and changes to tracked files), but it will only do work on the files that you add to a stage to be committed.

Example for committing the files in your "stage"

```
git commit
```

Example for pushing your local repo (whatever you have committed to your local repo) to github

```
git push
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to be able to use it on the command line, but if all else fails I'll use this. :f
(Or both.)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is clone your git repository. From terminal `cd` to the directory you want the project in and do

`git clone https://github.com/[username]/[repository].git`

Remember **not** to use `sudo` as you will mess up the remote permissions.

You then need to commit any changes locally, i.e your `git commit -m` and then you can do.

`git push`

This will update the **remote** repository.

Lastly if you need to update your **local** project `cd` to the required directory and then:

`git pull`

Answer (score 0):

- To start working on the project in linux, clone the repo to linux machine. Add the ssh public key to github. Add your username and email to git-config.
- For GUI you can use gitg.

PS : Get used to git cli, It is worth to spend time on it.